# Accessing a class variable directly (using dot notation) or via a function?

Tags: swift, variable-assignment, access-control, class-design, variable-declaration

```
class ThermometerClass {
    var temperature: Double = 0.0

    func registerTemperature(_ temperature: Double) {
        self.temperature = temperature
    }
}

let thermometerClass = ThermometerClass()

thermometerClass.temperature = 56.0

thermometerClass.registerTemperature(56.0)
```

I can access temperature directly by using dot notation and also with the function what is the difference in this two.

Comment: Where did you find this code? The context might help us find out what this code is trying to illustrate.

Comment: I found this code in the interview question. Below is the link https://www.raywenderlich.com/762435-swift-interview-questions-and-answers in Intermediate Written Questions question 2

Comment: The code shown in the link doesn't match the code you posted here. The code in the link called `registerTemperature` instead of using dot notation because `temperature` has a private setter. But that's not true in your code.

Comment: The link I share is just the reference.

Comment: I would recommend you read this post I made, explaining the purpose of getters/setters in most languages, and why they're not at all applicable to Swift: https://github.com/amomchilov/Blog/blob/master/Stop%20writing%20getters%20and%20setters%20in%20Swift.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class member `temperature` is not well designed.  It lacks encapsulation.

- The direct access changes the variable with little control. You have to know the internals of the class to be sure that the change doesn't lead to an inconsistent state. You cannot totally prevent the attempt to set an illegal value very easily.
- The access via the function is designed deliver some promises, regardless of the internal details. Access via a function is more controlled: if the change of the temperature would require additional information (e.g. hygrometry because you expect to correlate in time both measurements, or timestamp from an external atomic clock) the function could required it, whereas variables can always be changed individually.
- Moreover, if the thermometer will one day get some special behavior (e.g. update the display in the user's preferred unit of measure, or raise an alarm under some conditions), the function could make sure it is done.

So the access via the function is the safer approach, since it will protect you against future evolution of that class.

This being said, the design of the class could be improved:

- The encapsulation should be enforced, making the variable private.  The class users would then be forced to the proper use of `registerTemperature()` .
- For convenience, you could make a setter on a wrapper property: this seems to give direct public access to a variable but when its value is changed the setter is executed, to ensure the promises of such changes are held.

***Edit to avoid ambiguous wording:*** property observers (`willSet` and `didSet`) allow to produce additional effects when a public variable is changed directly. So direct changes do not prevent additional effects. But this require the class designer to have such direct changes in mind. And the change is less controlled than in a function. For example, you cannot totally prevent the effects of an illegal change: you could reverse a wrong change in didSet, but willSet would then be called twice; once with the illegal value, one after the reversing.

Comment: This is a correct answer for most languages, but not for Swift. "The direct access changes the variable with little control." Direct access to a variable isn't possible in Swift. You're always going through a property, which at any moment can be changed from a stored property (allowing others to indirectly mutate instance variables), to a computed property (allowing you to execute arbitrary code), without breaking the API/ABI.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica I think we are playing with words here. What you are telling us about properties is true with any language allowing to define custom getters and setters. The fact that it’s easier to make evolutions in property (eg from stored to computed) doesn’t change my argument about evolutions that would require a grouped change of several properties, a controlled change (eg temperature under ctrl of user id): the use of methods is easier to spot/refactor in such case than direct (ie without method). I agree, this benefit is mostly for writing and less for reading.

Comment: @Alexander-ReinstateMonica But thanks for the constructive and challenging argument :)

Comment: "What you are telling us about properties is true with any language allowing to define custom getters and setters." That's not quite true. Take C# for example. It has properties. But it also allows direct ivar access. My argument doesn't apply there. Once someone couples to your ivars, you lose control (unless you can accept doing an API breaking change). That's not the case if someone coupled to your properties. That would be totally fine, because at any moment you can change them from trivial getters/setters, to interception points for arbitrary code execution

Comment: I do agree with your answers' second point (about adding params), where you want to have named actions that express intent, and have params associated with them. Point 1 and point 3 don't hold, however.